# Prove that the product of four consecutive natural numbers are not the square of an integer

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

> Prove that the product of four consecutive natural numbers are not the square of an integer

Would appreciate any thoughts and feedback on my suggested proof, which is as follows:

Let $f(n) = n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3) $.
Multiplying out the expression and refactoring it in a slightly different way gives
$$f(n)  = n^4 + 6n^3+11n^2+6n \\= n^4 + 6n^3 + 9n^2 + 2n^2 + 6n = (n^2 + 3n)^2 + 2n(n+3). \tag{1}\label{1} $$

We want to show that the only possible way for $ f(n) $ to be the square of an integer is if $ f(n) = (n^2 + 3n +1 ) ^2. $ We show this by proving that $ (n^2+3n)^2 < f(n) < (n^2+3n+2)^2 $. The left-hand side follows immediately from $(1)$, since $ 2n(n+3) > 0 $ for all $ n \geq 1 $, and the right-hand side can be verified  by multiplying out both sides:
$$ 
\begin{align}
(n^2+3n)^2 + 2n(n+3) &< (n^2+3n+2)^2  \\ \iff
n^4 + 6n^3 + 11n^2 + 6n &< n^4 + 9n^2 + 4 + 6n^3+4n^2+12n \\ \iff
0 &< 2n^2 + 6n + 4
\end{align}
$$
which is true for all  $n \geq 1 $. Now we note that $n^2+3n = n(n+3)$ is even since one of the factors $n$ or $n+3$ is even for all $n$. It follows that $ n^2+3n+1$ must be odd, and so $ (n^2+3n+1)^2 $ must be odd. But $ f(n) $ must be even, since either $n$ and $(n+2)$ is even, or $(n+1)$ and $(n+3)$ is even and an even number multiplied by an odd number is an even number. So $f(n) \neq (n^2 + 3n +1)$ and therefore $f(n)$ cannot be the square of an integer for all $n \geq 1 $.

Comment: I haven't checked all the multiplications, but it looks right otherwise.

Comment: Note: You can show that $(n^2 + 3n )^2 < f(n) < (n^2 + 3n + 1)^2 $ without that much more work than what you already have.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that too.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is perfect and detailed.

Another alternative shorter approach based on observation is if we can consider $n(n+2)=k$ and then redefine the function as:
$$\begin{align*}f(k) &= k(k+2)\\ f(k) &= (k+1)^2-1\end{align*}$$

Now, we need to prove that $f(k)$ is not the square of an integer.
Well, there exists no two squares of a nonzero integer that differ by 1.
Hope that helps!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. @AbhinavLenka ! For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks. That is a nice way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3) +1$ is a square.

Comment: Please check OP's exact question and tags.